# Communicating between one ServerSocket and several Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, networking

im trying to make my ServerSocket communicate with more then one Socket, but i dont know how, so far i realized that invoking serverSocket.accept() would return a socket to communicate between server and the first socket, but then when the second and on are trying to connect to the ServerSocket, it lets them connect, but doesnt get a new socket to communicate with them, so, how do i communicate with the second Socket and on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you need to spawn a new thread if you want to communicate with both sockets at the same time.

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(... params ...);
while(isRunning) {
    Socket socket = ss.accept();
    Runnable r = new SocketHandler(socket); // write the socket handler class
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
```

Now obviously there are many, many improvements you can make to this. The most obvious would be holding on to the references of r and/or t so you have better/tighter control over them, and the ability to stop them at will. But those features are well beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Well, all of the accepting can be done on your server thread. You just need to pass the socket generated by `ss.accept()` to your handler thread.

Comment: so hypotheticaly speaking sequential calls to accept() would keep returning diffrent sockets that could accomplish communication with diffrent devices?

Comment: That's right - every call to `ss.accept()` produces a different socket. The call will block until a new socket is available. It will never return the same socket twice.